# Logrotate deleting instead of rotating

Tags: linux, debian, logrotate

This is my logrotate configuration

```
/var/log/abc/*.log {
missingok
compress
sharedscripts
create 640 root root
postrotate
/etc/init.d/abc reload
endscript

}
```

When i run this manually as `logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/abc` then instead of rotating log file for ex `xyz.log` to `xyz.log.1.gz` it deletes that log file.

So at present i have `xyz.log` and then `xyz.log.2.gz` but no `xyz.log.1.gz`.

I am not able to understand this behaviour of logrotate.

Comment: Have you tried running it with `-d`. Do you have `rotate <n>` statement in your config?

Comment: @Fox I didn't run it with `-d` and whatever is given above is in config. Also since i am giving this configuration file to logrotate directly i do not think it matters what parameters are present in `/etc/logrotate.conf`

Comment: My questions were pointers to a way to find out what's happening and a pointer to a probable solution. But if you feel like being defensive, I'm not going to argue.

Comment: Are you sure you have enough disk space?

Answer (score 1):

Check the contents of the init script, `/etc/init.d/abc`. When called with the `reload` command, it should at least stop writing to it by closing its corresponding file descriptor (that by this time would point to the path `/var/log/abc/xyz.log.1`) and start writing freshly to `/var/log/abc/xyz.log`.

Comment: This is what is present for reload command in init script `start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --oknodo --signal HUP --exec /usr/sbin/abc`

Comment: Check the behavior of `/usr/sbin/abc` when it is sent a `SIGHUP`. Does it setup a handler? If so then what does the handler do?

Comment: @shivams One interesting question here is how you got the compressed archive, `/var/log/abc/xyz.log.2.gz`? It will be helpful if you could update the question and provide details about the steps taken, starting from when the daemon was running (the process writing to `/var/log/abc/xyz.log` and you were yet to run `logrotate` by hand.